# Elasticsearch dynamic_templates regex matching

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like `userId` field to be `long` type where it appears on the document.
Below only works for the top `userId` field. 
How to make it pick up from inner objects?

```
   "mappings": {

     "dynamic_templates" : [
         {
             "userId" : {
               "match" : ".*userId.*|userId",
               "match_pattern": "regex",
                 "mapping" : {
                   "type" : "long"
                 }
             }
         }
     ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#path-match-unmatch) you should try `path_match`:

```
   "mappings": {

     "dynamic_templates" : [
         {
             "userId" : {
               "path_match" : ".*userId*",
                 "mapping" : {
                   "type" : "long"
                 }
             }
         }
     ]
```